# Compile the source code with two different set of dependencies in single build.gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I am working on gradle script where I have two separate list of cognos and other dependencies .

list 1:

```
cognos:a:10.1.1
cognos:b:10.1.1
cognos:c:10.1.1
cognos:d:10.1.1
com:axis:2.0.3
com:webroot:5.0.3
```

and List 2:

```
cognos:a:10.2.2
cognos:b:10.2.2
cognos:c:10.2.2
cognos:d:10.2.2
traven:nt:10.5.0
traven:txtx:5.2.1
```

I need to compile my source code first with list 1 dependenciesand then list 2 dependencies and publish the artifact with below name in artifactory.

Artifact with list 1 and list 2 dependencies

```
abc-1.0.0-cognos10.1.1
abc-1.0.0-cognos10.2.2
```

I can do it with build.gradle but I can do it in two separate build.gradle scripts.I am not sure how we can achieve this goal in signle build.gradle script.Can someone have any idea how to achieve it in single build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'


version = '1.0'
sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7

//create a single Jar with all dependencies
task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Jar File Example',  
            'Implementation-Version': version,
            'Main-Class': 'com.mkyong.DateUtils'
    }
    baseName = project.name + '-all'
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}

//Get dependencies from Maven central repository
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

//Project dependencies
dependencies {
    compile 'cognos:a:10.1.1
    compile  'cognos:b:10.1.1'
    compile  'cognos:c:10.1.1'
    compile  'cognos:d:10.1.1'
    compile 'traven:nt:10.5.0'
    compile 'traven:txtx:5.2.1'
}
```

Comment: Would you be open to using an external "driver" script to call this one gradle file several times with version as a parameter?

Comment: can u please elaborate more?

Answer (score 0):

In your build.gradle, replace cognos and app version with a parameter:

```
version = "1.0.0-cognos${cognosVersion}"
sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7

...

dependencies {
    compile "cognos:a:${cognosVersion}"
    compile "cognos:b:${cognosVersion}"
    compile "cognos:c:${cognosVersion}"
    compile "cognos:d:${cognosVersion}"
}
```

Then you can manually run this a few times:

```
gradle build -PcognosVersion=xxxx
```

If you want to automate that as well, you can write a second gradle driver script release.gradle:

```
defaultTasks  'performRelease'

task performRelease() << {
    ['10.1.1','10.2.2'].each{
        def tempTask = tasks.create(name: "execute_$it", type: GradleBuild)
        tempTask.buildFile='build.gradle'
        tempTask.tasks = ['build']
        tempTask.startParameter.projectProperties = [cognosVersion: it]
        tempTask.execute()
    }
}
```

which you can executes as: `gradle -b release.gradle`

Comment: I agree but in future if they add some dependencies in the list 1 and 2 which are totally different or the dependency which are in list 1 and not in 2 then this solution will not work

Comment: In the future, it is always possible to add something to your build script that will break your current setup. My answer addresses the problem as stated in your question. It is easy enough to extend it to the situation you're describing.

Comment: I updated my question now so it will give you more clear idea about the requirement,

Comment: Make the entire dependency list a parameter instead of cognos version then.